# convert older version to version 4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

**Following code is older version of pine script, i converted into version 4 and result is different. in older version result is correct. pls help me same result in version 4**

```
study(title="CD_Average Daily Range Zones", shorttitle="CD_Daily High/Low Zones V01", overlay=true) 

OPEN=security(tickerid, 'D', open) 

//ADR L
dayrange=(high - low)

r1 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[1]) 
r2 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[2]) 
r3 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[3]) 
r4= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[4])
r5= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[5])
r6 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[6]) 
r7 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[7]) 
r8 = security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[8]) 
r9= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[9])
r10= security(tickerid, 'D', dayrange[10])


adr_10 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+r10) /10
adr_9 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9) /9
adr_8 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8) /8
adr_7 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7) /7
adr_6 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6) /6
adr_5 = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5) /5
adr_4 = (r1+r2+r3+r4) /4
adr_3 = (r1+r2+r3) /3
adr_2= (r1+r2)/2
adr_1 = r1

//plot 
adrhigh10=plot((OPEN+(adr_10/2)) , title="ADR High10",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
adrlow10=plot((OPEN-(adr_10/2)), title="ADR LOW10",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)

adrhigh5=plot((OPEN+(adr_5/2)) , title="ADR High5",style=circles,color=red,linewidth=2) 
adrlow5=plot((OPEN-(adr_5/2)), title="ADR LOW5",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=2)

fill(adrlow10,adrlow5,color=lime)
fill(adrhigh10,adrhigh5,color=maroon)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with the gaps and lookahead parameters.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_security

Try setting one of them to false or true and then both of them to false or true
I'm sure one of those 4 combinations will give the same results as your v1 script :)

Comment: can u pls suggest something on this.. there is indicator on TV but its locked hence looking for code, i shared half logic... 

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73546925/revisions